# Swift 2 Json Parsing Array and Get Just "nil"

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to code a simple clipboard translator of myself. So I use an API but I can't get the real data in JSON.

Here is my Code

```
import Cocoa

var url = NSURL(string: "http://api.fanyi.baidu.com/api/trans/vip/translate?q=%E6%B8%AC%E8%A9%A6%E7%94%A8%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97&from=cht&to=zh&appid=20160223000013220&salt=1435660288&sign=0a697bbcbd4686b168cb3255ffea1427")

var data: NSData
var json: AnyObject!


do{
    data = try NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached)
    json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
}

var transInfo: AnyObject! = json.objectForKey("trans_result['dst']")
```

In the URL, data of **trans_result["dst"]** is the answer i want. But from the code below i could only get a "nil" instead of "\u6d4b\u8bd5\u7528\u6587\u5b57"

How can I solve this problem? Was I missing something?

Comment: What is getting assigned to `data` and `json`?

Comment: You can't get the value in this way, you should get the `trans_result` first and then parse it into `NSArray` and then get the `dst` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this index

```
trans_result[0].dst
```

Visualize the json data with  [codebeautify](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer)

Comment: the question is in `Swift`, you can't do `json.trans_result[0].dst` in Swift

Comment: This is not a full correct answer, but follow your answer i found the final answer for me. `var transInfo: AnyObject! = json.objectForKey("trans_result")` `var dstInfo = transInfo[0]["dst"] as! String`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
do{
    data = try NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached)
   let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

    let arrResult = json["trans_result"]
    print("Result \(arrResult!![0]["src"])")
}catch {
    print("Error in json parsing")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made two mistakes here

1) You can't access the value of `dst` by doing `objectForKey("trans_result['dst']")`

2) There is one more layer between `trans_result` and `dst`, that means `json["trans_result"]` is not `Dictionary` but a `Array`

In order to get the value you need and make the code safe when unwrapping `Optional`:

```
if let array = json.objectForKey("trans_result") as? NSArray where array.count > 0{
    if let dst = array[0].objectForKey("dst") {
        print(dst)
    }
}
```